# Handling the HttpResponse from python

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I have been trying to retrieve an Array to my HTML page from my python script(view.py) which looks like this-

```
def archive(request):
    posts = BlogPost.objects.all()
    myVal = ["Dog Toys", "Dog Bedding", "Dog Feeding", "Health & Hygiene"]
    t = loader.get_template("archive.html")
    c = Context({'myposts' : simplejson.dumps(myVal)})
    return HttpResponse(c)
```

My JavaScript on test.html looks like this -

```
<script>
    var results = '{{myposts}}';
    console.log(results);
</script>
```

The problem I have here is that my array is printed directly on the HTML page meaning my page source has only this -

```
1 : {'myposts': '["Dog Toys", "Dog Bedding", "Dog Feeding", "Health & Hygiene"]'}
```

i ams ure there is a way to overcome this, just not sure how to do it, I am working with Python/Django & JavaScript for the first time.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: is this helpful ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319896/decode-json-and-iterate-through-items-in-django-template

Comment: @AnkurGupta - To a certain extend yes, thank you, but my console.log(results) prints out a STRING of values [&quot;Dog Toys&quot;, &quot;Dog Bedding&quot;, &quot;Dog Feeding&quot;, &quot;Health &amp; Hygiene&quot;] any idea why its not an Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can add to the Hellpain`s answer next:

```
var result = "{{myposts|join:'/'}}".split('/');
```

So firstly python list is joined to the string and then splited by javascript into array

Comment: This works perfectly for me, thanks alot, but i have a tiny problem one of my values look like this "Health &amp; Hygiene" how can i make it look like "Health & Hygiene"

Comment: Try mark string as safe:
`var result = "{{myposts|join:'/'|safe}}".split('/');`

Comment: Marking string as safe in a view.py works for me:
`myVal = ["Dog Toys", "Dog Bedding", "Dog Feeding", mark_safe("Health & Hygiene")]` . Import `make_safe` as `from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe`

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
c = Context({'myposts' : mark_safe(myVal))
```

And then you need to leave out the quotes to get an array:

```
var results = {{myposts}};
```

Comment: I have a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &" and points to [&quot;Dog Toys&quot;, &quot;Dog Bedding&quot;, &quot;Dog Feeding&quot;, &quot;Health &amp; Hygiene&quot;], why does it get converted to special characters in the HTML page?

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
var results = '{{myposts}}';
```

with

```
var results = '{% for post in myposts %} {{ post }}, {% endfor %}';
```

You generate javascript in html. You can directly transmit list to template:

```
c = Context({'myposts' : myVal})
```