# django/python reading json?

Tags: python, django, json, django-templates, python-2.7

I'm trying to learn django/python and I'm trying to figure out how to read json data...

I have something like :

```
{
  region: {
    span: {
       latitude_delta: 0.08762885999999526,
       longitude_delta: 0.044015180000002374
    },
    center: {
       latitude: 37.760948299999995,
       longitude: -122.4174594
    }
  },...
}
```

I'm trying to read specific data in my html page. Right now this json data is being displayed in the html page.

The source of the this json comes from this:

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response),mimetype="application/json")
```

I'm trying to figure out the django/python convention of getting specific data? Am I supposed to do a for each loop? I come from a self taught php background, and I'm trying to teach myself python/django.

Thank you

edit:

I also have this in my view.py before the return HttpResponse

```
    try:
        conn = urllib2.urlopen(signed_url, None)
        try:
            response = json.loads(conn.read())
        finally:
            conn.close()
    except urllib2.HTTPError, error:
        response = json.loads(error.read())
```

Comment: "Something like"? This is neither valid JSON nor Python...

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345076/django-parse-json-in-my-template-using-javascript

Comment: ? this is a bit confusing... you manage to create the json using json.dumps(response), response should be your data as python objects.  json.dumps() turns it into json.  The opposite of json.dumps() is json.loads()

Comment: @monkut I edited my post. I think it is because I had the json.loads prior to the return?

Comment: json.loads() loads the given json data to python objects, which you can access.  What is your question here?

Comment: @monkut I'm trying to figure out how to get specific data when doing for loops? Or what is the python convention? Typically when I'm dealing with PHP I would do something like `foreach($datas as $data){echo $data['region'];}` or something.

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest way to read json in html (Send by Django)

```
def sendJson(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        context = {"name":"Json Sample Data"}
        return render_to_response('name.html',context)
```

Django Template Html Code

```
<div class="col-md-9 center">
    <span class="top-text">{{name}}</span>
</div>
```

Now according to your:

```
 def sendJson(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        jsonData = {
          region: {
           span: {
            latitude_delta: 0.08762885999999526,
            longitude_delta: 0.044015180000002374
          },
          center: {
            latitude: 37.760948299999995,
            longitude: -122.4174594
          }
        }
       }
       data = json.dumps(jsonData)
       return HttpResponse(data, content_type="application/json")
```

you can read this data by using jquery also

another example to create json and read in html

url.py

```
url(r'^anotherexample/$', 'views.anotherexample', name="anotherexample"),
```

view.py

```
 def anotherexample(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       _date = strftime("%c")
       response_data = {}
       response_data['status'] = 'taken'
       response_data['issueTakenTime'] = _date
       return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

Html view and jquery

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/anotherexample/",
    // contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    data: { csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",   // < here 
        status : "taken"
      },
    type: "POST",
    error: function(res) {
      console.log("errr", res)
    },
    success: function(res) {
      console.log("res", res)}
    })
```

Comment: This is the same what I have been using.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want to loop over, where, or how, but basic loops work like this:

```
data = {"key1":[1,2], "key":[4,5]}
for key, values in data.iteritems():
    print key, values
```

Comment: This would go into my views.py under the same `def`? example if all my code is in `def search(request)`, I'm just trying to see if I'm supposed to loop inside the .html file? or loop in the view.py file? I dunno if that makes sense to you?

Comment: hmmm... well you can create a loop and parse objects in the view, or loop in the template.  I would say generally it's easier to manage data in the view to put it into a clean structure before passing to the template.  If you haven't already I suggest you try the python tutorial and then the django tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the solution through this link: [Decode json and Iterate through items in django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319896/decode-json-and-iterate-through-items-in-django-template)

It helped me and hopefully it'll help someone else who has the same problem as me.

Thanks